# Find all IPs from subnet in perl

Tags: perl, ip-address

I have an IP with subnetmask and want to create a table in which every row is an IP.

Kind of like this:

```
IP          | MAC  | Alive 
192.168.1.1 | ...  | yes
192.168.1.2 | ...  | no
192.168.1.3 | ...  | yes
...
```

For a range with subnet /24, this is easy because I can generate a for loop from 0 to 254 but I'm having trouble with generating the table with a /21 subnet. Is there a way to find in perl what the minimum host, the maximum host and everything in between is?

I have checked the `Net::IP` and the `NetAddr::IP` module but don't seem a solution for my problem. However, I'm a perl newbie so it could be that I overlooked it.

edit:
found how to find first and last address:

```
my $range = "IP/subnet" ;
my $ip = new Net::IP ($range) || die;
print $ip->ip (), "\n";
print $ip->last_ip (), "\n";
```

Now I need to find the IPs in between

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs for `Net::IP` has an example for how to do this in the [looping](http://search.cpan.org/~manu/Net-IP/IP.pm#looping) section.

Demo:

```
use Net::IP;

my $ip = new Net::IP("192.168.42.16/28");
do {
  print $ip->ip(), "\n";
} while (++$ip);
```

```
192.168.42.16
192.168.42.17
192.168.42.18
192.168.42.19
192.168.42.20
192.168.42.21
192.168.42.22
192.168.42.23
192.168.42.24
192.168.42.25
192.168.42.26
192.168.42.27
192.168.42.28
192.168.42.29
192.168.42.30
192.168.42.31
```

If you only have an IP in the desired range, not the prefix, you can compute the prefix from the address and netmask. Try something like this (there probably is a more clever way of achieving this with `Net::IP` though, but that's eluding me):

```
use Net::IP;

my $addr = "192.168.42.23";
my $len  = 28;

my $mid = new Net::IP($addr, 4);
my $mask = Net::IP::ip_get_mask($len, 4);
my $first = $mid->binip() & $mask;
my $ip = new Net::IP(Net::IP::ip_bintoip($first, 4)."/$len", 4);
do {
  print $ip->ip(), "\n";
} while (++$ip);
```

Comment: Just found that as well and tried, but it only works for me if I use the subnet address. It seems I need to know that and cannot use the first address. So it works with `192.168.0.0/21` and `192.168.0/21`, but not with `192.168.0.1/21`. The latter will return `undef` upon instantiation.

Comment: Added a way to get this subnet address from any address in the range. Not pretty though, I was sort of expecting a function that does just that but can't find it...

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with [NetAddr::IP](https://metacpan.org/pod/NetAddr::IP) and the [`nth` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/NetAddr::IP#nth-index). I created a helper sub that makes use of a singleton to create an iterator. You pass in any IP from the subnet and it gives you a code reference that you can to receive the next IP address object. It will do that until the range is exhausted, at which point it returns `undef`.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use NetAddr::IP;
use feature 'say';

sub make_ip_iterator {
    my $ip = shift;

    my $mask = NetAddr::IP->new($ip);

    my $i = 0;
    return sub {
        return $mask->nth($i++);
    }
}

my $iterator = make_ip_iterator('192.168.1.1/21');
while (my $ip = $iterator->()) {
    say $ip;
}
```

Because `$mask` and `$i` are lexical within the `make_ip_iterator` sub, you can call it multiple times and get distinct iterators back for different subnets that you use at the same time.

You could of course implement it with only a `while` loop and a counter variable because `nth()` will return `undef` when it's called with an index outside of the subnet, but this solution is more portable.

Comment: Important note about execution time: using the module `NETAddr::IP` and `nth method`is about 10 times faster than using `Net::IP` and looping, tested for the same CIDR range 192.0.0.0/24. I also tried in Bash with `nmap` : far far away, time unit is hours.